# Collection not defined error in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I keep getting the error

> Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Threads is not defined

while trying to iterate through a collection and print it into the page. To isolate the problem I have set it to print a button for each of the two threads I have preloaded in the database. I receive the error and no buttons are posted. Typing Threads.find().count(); in the console returns 2.

My code is as follows

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Threads = new Mongo.Collection('threads');
});

Template.threads.helpers({
    threads: function() {
        return Threads.find();
    }
});
```

And

```
<body>
    <div class="threads">
        {{> threads}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="threads">
    {{#each threads}}
          <button>Button!</button>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your collection declaration out of the `Meteor.startup` block.

I suspect that your template helper is first called before `Meteor.startup` fires, thus provoking the undefined identifier error.

Comment: Yes -- I was under the impression that `Meteor.startup` fired before all else. This was the solution.